# Laravel 5 Scope with additional queries

Tags: php, laravel

I want to show content to a specific page depending on the url.
So by calling the url mypage.com/menues/{city} I want to show all restaurants for a specific citiy.

I have this route:

```
Route::get('menues/{city?}', 'PagesController@menue');
```

And this Controler:

```
public function menue($city = null) {

  if ($city) {
    $restaurants = User::with(['articles' => function ($q){
      $q->nowpublished()->where('city', '=', 'Heilbronn');
    }])->get();
  } else {
    $restaurants = User::with(['articles' => function ($q){
      $q->nowpublished();
    }])->get();
  }

  return view('pages.menues')->withRestaurants($restaurants)                             
                             ->withCity($city);


}
```

I defined this scope in my Article Model:

```
  public function scopeNowPublished($query) {
    $zero = Carbon::today()->addHours(23)->addMinutes(59)->addSeconds(59);
    $query->whereBetween('published_at',[Carbon::today(),$zero])->orderBy('published_at','desc');
}
```

With the above code an QueryException is thrown.

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'city' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `articles` where `articles`.`user_id` in (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11) and `published_at` between 2016-10-06 00:00:00 and 2016-10-06 23:59:59 and `city` = Heilbronn order by `published_at` desc)
```

I am not sure if I can chain nowpublished() with the where clause...

Unfortunately I have no Idea how to fix this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does the article have field `city` ? I think the `User` has so the solution is to get the `where` method call out the relation query:

```
$restaurants = User::with(['articles' => function ($q){
  $q->nowpublished();
}])
->where('city', 'Heilbronn')
->get();
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the query from the error:

```
Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'city' in 'where clause'

(SQL: 
    select *
    from `articles`
    where `articles`.`user_id` in (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11)
    and `published_at` between 2016-10-06 00:00:00 and 2016-10-06 23:59:59
    and `city` = Heilbronn
    order by `published_at` desc
)
```

Which I'm guessing represents this part of your PHP code:

```
'articles' => function ($q){
  $q->nowpublished()->where('city', '=', 'Heilbronn');
}
```

It's looking for the column `city` on the table `articles`.

So the question for you is does the `articles` table have a `city` column?

You said in your question:

> I want to show all restaurants for a specific citiy

But your not even querying any `Restaurant` type entity, all I see is `User` and `Article`. Perhaps you are missing the `Restaturant` part of the query which is the issue? As we don't know your DB schema it's hard to say!

**EDIT**

To answer the other question you asked...

```
public function menue($city = null)
{
  // prep query so we don't write it twice
  $query = User::with(['articles' => function ($q){
      $q->nowpublished();
    }]);

  // Check city exists with users
  $city = User::where('city', $city)->get();

  // if it does then apply where
  if ($city) {
    $query->where('city', '=', $city)->get();
  }

  // get results from query
  $restaurants = $query->get();

  // return view with query results
  return view('pages.menues')
    ->withRestaurants($restaurants)
    ->withCity($city);

}
```

Comment: Thank you for the hint. Article doesn't contain city. this colmun belongs to the User.

Comment: Any advice for my new question above?

Comment: @Mamulasa - You should really update your question or make a new question. You can check if the city exists before your conditional statement.

Comment: @Mamulasa I've updated my answer to answer the second question you asked - hope that helps!

Comment: with you updated code I get this exception SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2031 (SQL: select * from `users` where `city` = ?)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125107/discussion-between-haakym-and-mamulasa).

Answer (score 0):

I have updated my code to

```
if ($city) {
    $restaurants = User::with(['articles' => function ($q){
      $q->nowpublished();
    }])->where('city', '=', $city)->get();
  } else {
    $restaurants = User::with(['articles' => function ($q){
      $q->nowpublished();
    }])->get();
  }
```

If I call a url with a city that doens't excist in my DB column, no results are shown and the page is empty. How can I display all entries if the city deosn't match a DB entry.

Comment: You should really update your question or make a new question - this is an answer